# SQL Server 2012 WHERE IN CONDITION IFF Case..WHEN

Tags: sql-server-2012, where-clause, case-when

I am using SQL Server 2012.  I am trying to set the WHERE clause with specific condition.  The PAE.CaseStatusId contains values 1, 2, 4, 8, 16.  The idea is to use Bitwise & to select condition for the WHERE.  For example, if @CaseStatusSum = 3, then select CaseStatusId IN (1, 2); if @CaseStatusSum = 4, then select CaseStatusId = 4 etc. I have problem to set the Condition with IFF or CASE.  I wonder if there is anyway to resolve this problem.  Any input is appreciated. Thank you.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getPagingPatientLiteByNameTest]
(
@CaseStatusSum INT,
@FilterCriteria NVARCHAR(50),
@PageNo INT = 1,
@PageSize INT = 10,
@SortColumn NVARCHAR(40) = 'OperationDate',
@SortOrder NVARCHAR(4) = 'DESC'
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE
@lFilter NVARCHAR(50),
@lSortCol NVARCHAR(40),
@lFirstRec INT,
@lLastRec INT,
@lTotalRows INT,


SET NOCOUNT OFF
/* Setting local variable */
SET @lFilter = LTRIM(RTRIM(@FilterCriteria))
SET @lSortCol = LTRIM(RTRIM(@SortColumn))
SET @lFirstRec = (@PageNo - 1 ) * @PageSize + 1
SET @lLastRec = @PageNo * @PageSize
SET @lTotalRows = @lLastRec  - @lFirstRec + 1


; WITH CTE_Results 
AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'OperationDate' AND @lSortCol = 'ASC')
          THEN OpDate
  END ASC,
  CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'OperationDate' AND @lSortCol = 'DESC')
          THEN OpDate
  END DESC,
  CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'HN' AND @lSortCol = 'ASC')
          THEN HN
  END ASC,
  CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'HN' AND @lSortCol = 'DESC')
          THEN HN
  END DESC,
  CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = '')
          THEN OpDate
  END DESC
  ) AS ROWNUM,
    Count(*) over () AS TotalCount,
    Id,
    RecOut,
    CaseStatusId,
    LastName,
  OpDate
    FROM PAE
    WHERE 
        ( CaseStatusId = (
            CASE @CaseStatusSum
                WHEN 1 THEN 1
                WHEN 2 THEN 2
                WHEN 4 THEN 4
                WHEN 8 THEN 8
                WHEN 16 THEN 16
            END )

      /*  MS SQL Server 2012
          In the following commented section, neither IIF nor IF..ELSE work. 
          My goal is IF @CaseStatusSum = 3 THEN select CaseStatusSum IN (1, 2) and
          IF @CaseStatusSum = 8 THEN select CaseStatusSum IN (8) / CaseStatusSum = 8

      -- here is the problem, I am unable to get 1, 2 out of IIF to the IN condition
            OR CaseStatusId IN (IIF(@CaseStatusSum = 3, (1 2), 0)) 

      -- here is the problem: IF is not allow in this structure
            OR IF (@CaseStatusSum = 3)
                    BEGIN
                         CaseStatusId IN (1, 2)
                    END
              ELSE
                    BEGIN
                         CaseStatusId = 4
                    END
              END IF  
      */

            OR CaseStatusId = (
            CASE @CaseStatusSum
                WHEN 1 THEN 4
                WHEN 2 THEN 2
                WHEN 4 THEN 4
                WHEN 8 THEN 8
                WHEN 16 THEN 16
            END )
        )

        AND RecOut > getDate()
        AND (@lFilter IS NULL OR (LastName LIKE @lFilter))
)
 SELECT
  TotalCount,
    Id,
    RecOut,
    CaseStatusId,
    LastName,
  OpDate
FROM CTE_Results
WHERE 
  ROWNUM BETWEEN @lFirstRec AND @lLastRec
ORDER BY ROWNUM ASC


END
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are maximum of 3 CaseStatusId scenarios at any given time, I could use the OR in there WHERE clause.
Case 1, 2, 4, 8, or 16  - has one unique combination
Case 3, 5, 6, and 7 - have more than one combination.
Case 3: combinations 1, 3
Case 5: combinations 1, 4
Case 6: combinations: 2, 4
Case 7: combinations: 1, 2, 4

```
Declare
@lCaseStatusId1 INT,
@lCaseStatusId2 INT,
@lCaseStatusId3 INT
:
:
SET NOCOUNT OFF
/* Setting local variable */
IF @AssignedTo < 0
    SET @lAssignedTo = null
ELSE
    SET @lAssignedTo = @AssignedTo

IF @CaseStatusSum = 16
BEGIN
    SET @lCaseStatusId1 = 16
    SET @lCaseStatusId2 = null
    SET @lCaseStatusId3 = null
END
ELSE IF @CaseStatusSum = 8
BEGIN
    SET @lCaseStatusId1 = 8
    SET @lCaseStatusId2 = null
    SET @lCaseStatusId3 = null
END
ELSE IF @CaseStatusSum = 7
BEGIN
    SET @lCaseStatusId1 = 4
    SET @lCaseStatusId2 = 2
    SET @lCaseStatusId3 = 1
END
ELSE IF @CaseStatusSum = 6
BEGIN
    SET @lCaseStatusId1 = 4
    SET @lCaseStatusId2 = 2
    SET @lCaseStatusId3 = null
END
ELSE IF @CaseStatusSum = 5
BEGIN
    SET @lCaseStatusId1 = 4
    SET @lCaseStatusId2 = 1
    SET @lCaseStatusId3 = null
END
ELSE IF @CaseStatusSum = 4
BEGIN
    SET @lCaseStatusId1 = 4
    SET @lCaseStatusId2 = null
    SET @lCaseStatusId3 = null
END
ELSE IF @CaseStatusSum = 3
BEGIN
    SET @lCaseStatusId1 = 2
    SET @lCaseStatusId2 = 1
    SET @lCaseStatusId3 = null
END
ELSE IF @CaseStatusSum = 2
BEGIN
    SET @lCaseStatusId1 = 2
    SET @lCaseStatusId2 = null
    SET @lCaseStatusId3 = null
END
ELSE IF @CaseStatusSum = 1
BEGIN
    SET @lCaseStatusId1 = 1
    SET @lCaseStatusId2 = null
    SET @lCaseStatusId3 = null
END
:
:
    WHERE  
        (CaseStatusId = @lCaseStatusId1
        OR CaseStatusId = @lCaseStatusId2
        OR CaseStatusId = @lCaseStatusId3)
            AND RecOut > getDate()
:
:
```